# Uploaded images not showing up on web page

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set the profile picture and banner of a user on my Springboot/Thymeleaf web application, which I'm running and hosting from my system.

Uploading works fine - the file is written properly to it's folder and it's file path is saved as a String to a MySQL database.

When trying to display that same image from the file path, it throws a 404 and says the image could not be loaded.

I set the Filename and path in a controller with Springboot:

```java
byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
int extIndex = file.getOriginalFilename().length() - 4;
String newFileName = businessId + file.getOriginalFilename().substring(extIndex);
Path path = Paths.get("c://Users//farru//git//CapstoneNAFJ//" +
"CapstoneNAFJ//src//main//resources//static//img//" + newFileName);
Files.write(path, bytes);
            
String imgPath = "img/" + newFileName;
            
currBusiness.setBanner(imgPath);
businessRepository.save(currBusiness);
```

I then try to edit the source of an img tag with Thymeleaf

```html
<img th:src="@{${business.banner}}" alt="profile picture">
```

The weird thing is: it *sometimes* works, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Even weirder, after I've deleted the images from the folder, if I go on the web page and change the src attribute of the img tag with Inspect Element, the images will show flawlessly. Every single one, despite me clearing my cache (and recompiling the code, dropping and building back the MySQL tables, etc.)

Comment: My guess is `//` is nonsense here and you mean double backslash, the other slash, or a single slash which is handled by Java.

Comment: What does the `<img>` tag look like? Is the `src` path correct? When you "open in new tab" with this URL do you get anything?

Comment: Sorry, @tadman! Turns out the problem wasn't with the code itself. Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't an issue with my code, it was simply a setting in eclipse that meant the IDE wouldn't check for updates to the project folder (in this case, the image files added).

Fixed this by checking *Preferences* => *General* => *Workspace* => *Refresh using native hooks or polling*

Comment: Nice to post an answer rather than delete this and have this knowledge lost to the sands of time. May help someone else out some day.